# How do I get the minimum distance between a point and a parabola using Python?

Tags: python

What I want to make is angrybirds game.
There is a requirement
1.Draw a rectangle randomly between 100 and 200 in length and length 10 in length.
2. Receive the user inputting the launch speed and the launch angle.
3. Project shells square from origin (0,0).
4. If the shell is hit, we'll end it, or we'll continue from number two.
So this is what I wrote

```
import turtle as t
import math
import random

def square():
    for i in range(4):
       t.forward(10)
       t.left(90)

def fire():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    speed = int(input("속도:"))
    angle = int(input("각도:"))
    vx = speed * math.cos(angle * 3.14/180.0)
    vy = speed * math.sin(angle * 3.14/180.0)
    while t.ycor() >= 0:
        vx = vx
        vy = vy - 10
        x = x + vx
        y = y + by
        t.goto(x,y)

    d = t.distance(d1+5, 5)

    if d < 10:
        print("Game End")
    else:
        t.up()
        t.goto(0,0)
        t.down()
        fire()

d1 = random.randint(100,200)
t.up()
t.forward(d1)
t.down()

square()
t.up()
t.goto(0,0)
t.down()

fire()
```

I want to get an answer to this problem.
The problem is I want to calculate a minimum distance between a point(target point is (d1+5,5)) and a parabola which turtle draw. so I try to find an answer searching in google, python book, but I can't find it.
please help me

Comment: The program asks for input, but I can't read chinese. What does it say?

Comment: Also, the program goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in your game: the fire's y coordinate often goes way below 0, making it hard to end up with the  box.

```
import turtle as t
from math import sin,cos,pi
import random

def square():
    for i in range(4):
       t.forward(10)
       t.left(90)

def fire():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    speed = int(input("속도:"))
    angle = int(input("각도:"))
    vx = speed *cos(angle * pi/180.0)
    vy = speed * sin(angle * pi/180.0)
    while True:
        vx = vx
        vy = vy - 10
        x = x + vx
        if y + vy >= -10:
            y = y + vy
            t.goto(x,y)
        else:
            break
    d = t.distance(d1+5, 5)
    print(d)

    if d < 10:
        print("Game End")
    else:
        t.up()
        t.home()
        t.down()
        fire()

d1 = random.randint(100,200)
t.up()
t.forward(d1)
t.down()
square()
t.up()
t.home()
t.down()
fire()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic calculus to determine this minimum distance.

Let's suppose you have point (x1, y1) and parabola y = ax^2 + bx + c

Distance between point and parabola at specific x let's name d(x)

d(x) = sqrt((x-x1)^2 + (ax^2 + bx + c - y1)^2)

We can find local minimum by calculating derivative and equate to 0 (we can ignore squared root and 2 - increasing functions won't change minimum):

x-x1 + (b + 2ax)(c + bx + ax^2 - y1) = 0

This is cubic equation, which you can solve analytically (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) or numerically (here you can use numpy, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)

Those 2 methods will give you x coordinate of point on parable minimizing the distance. Now you just have to calculate it, using d(x) formula.